# Creating nested dictionaries from a list

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry for a 3rd similar question but I'm still trying to work through what my output would be.

Ideally I would have programmatic way using a function to take a list of values and store them in a nested dictionary.

`values = [1,2.0,3.0,1,1,3,4.0,2,3.0, 2.0]`

The result of the function would provide a dictionary that looks like this:

```
types: {

   'int' : {
       
       '1': [1,1,1,],
       '2': [2],
       '3': [3]
       }
    'float' : {
       '2.0' : 2,
       '3.0' : 2,
       '4.0' : 1
      }
}
```

Where the int dictionary just stores the occurrences of each value and the float dictionary stores the counts of the instances.

This is what I have but I'm running into problems with the logic of creating the sub dictionaries.

```
values = [1,2.0,3.0,1,1,3,4.0,2,3.0, 2.0]

types = {}
for obj in values:
      k = type(obj).__name__
      types[k] = types.get(k, {})
      if isinstance(obj, int):
          types['int'] = obj
      elif isinstance(obj, float):
         types['float'][obj] = types['float'].get(obj,0)
            
print(types)
```

I started with a for loop to try to figure out the logic before try the

```
def summarize_numbers(list):
return type
```

function syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code as much as possible

```
values = [1,2.0,3.0,1,1,3,4.0,2,3.0, 2.0]

types = {}
for obj in values:
      k = type(obj).__name__
      types[k] = types.get(k, {})
      if isinstance(obj, int):
            types[k].setdefault(obj, []).append(obj) # append to default list
      elif isinstance(obj, float):
        types[k].setdefault(obj, 0)  # default int 0
        types[k][obj] += 1           # increment

print(types) # {'int': {1: [1, 1, 1], 3: [3], 2: [2]}, 
                'float': {2.0: 2, 3.0: 2, 4.0: 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should help you reach the solution you need

```
values = [1,2.0,3.0,1,1,3,4.0,2,3.0, 2.0]
types= {'int':{}, 'float':{}}

for obj in values:
    if isinstance(obj, int):
        obj = str(obj)
        types['int'][obj] = types['int'].get(obj, [])
        types['int'][obj].append(int(obj))
    elif isinstance(obj, float):
        obj = str(obj)
        types['float'][obj] = types['float'].get(obj, 0) + 1

print(types)
```

Output:

```
{'int': {'1': [1, 1, 1], '3': [3], '2': [2]}, 'float': {'2.0': 2, '3.0': 2, '4.0': 1}}
```